# Hibernate insert with join and foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some problem with insert in hibernate.

Suppose I have 2 entity

```
@Entity
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int user_id;

    String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "utente_id")
    list<City> cities;
}

@Entity
public class City{
    int user_id
    int city_id
}
```

if I try a create class User and add a list of city but when I try to save, receive this error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Foreign key constraint violation occurred

this because `user_id` in class `City` must be equal at `user_id` in `User`, but hibernate first inserts and then updates.
How do i revolve this?

Comment: Show your annotations on `City` class. And example of code where you get Exception. It seems that you need `ManyToMany` relation here.

Answer (score 0):

Try first to persist the User object to DB.
Only after you persist you can get the generated value of user_id.

Then you can create the City object, set the user_id field, and persist it.